# How to make a distinction between two equals objects in a Sorted collection?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I may be wrong but for me, we can override equals for an object so that you consider them has being  meaningfully equals.
All the entry in a map have distinct keys, and all the entries in set have distinct values (not meaningfully equals)

But when using a TreeMap or a TreeSet, you can provide a comparator.
I noticed that when a comparator is provided, the object's equals method is bypassed, and two objets are considered equals when the comparator returns 0.
Thus, we have 2 objects but inside of a map keyset, or a set, only one is kept.

I'd like to know if it is possible, using a sorted collection, to make a distinction for two different instances.

Here's an easy sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
    String s1 = new String("toto");
    String s2 = new String("toto");
    System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    set.add(s1);
    set.add(s2);
    System.out.println(set.size());
}
```

Notice that using new String("xxx") bypass the use of the String pool, thus s1 != s2.
I'd like to know how to implement a comparator so that the set size is 2 and not 1.

The main question is: for two distinct instances of the same String value, how can i return something != 0 in my comparator?

Note that i'd like to have that comparator respect the rules:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementer must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.
>
> It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals."

I can use a trick like:

```
public int compare(String s1,String s2) {
  if s1.equals(s2) { return -1 }
  ...
}
```

It seems to work fine but the rules are not respected since compare(s1,s2) != -compare(s2,s1)

So is there any elegant solution to this problem?

---

**Edit: for those wondering why i ask such a thing. It's more by curiosity than any real life problem.**

But i've already been in a situation like that and though about a solution to this problem:

Imagine you have:

```
class Label {
  String label;
}
```

For each label you have an associated String value.
Now what if you want to have a map, label->value.
But now what if you want to be able to have twice the same label as a map key?
Ex
"label" (ref1) -> value1
"label" (ref2) -> value2
You can implement equals so that two distinct Label instances are not equals -> i think it works for HashMap.

But what if you want to be able to sort these Label objects by alphabetical order? 
You need to provide a comparator or implement comparable.
But how can we make an order distinction between 2 Labels having the same label?
We must! 
compare(ref1,ref2) must not return 0. But should it return -1 or 1 ?
We could compare the memory address or something like that to take such a decision but i think it's not possible in Java...

Comment: My opinion is that you shouldnot use Strings as identifiers (keys for maps) in your case, since they are not real identifiers. How would you know anyway which one of the two `Label` Objects you want if you have a String `"label"`?

Comment: this is just an exemple, but actually i don't only have the "label" but i got to separate references

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Guava, you can make use of [`Ordering.arbitrary()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#arbitrary%28%29), which will impose an additional order on elements which remains consistent for the life of the VM. You can use this to break ties in your Comparator in a consistent way.

However you could be using the wrong data structure. Have you considered using a `Multiset` (e.g. `TreeMultiset`), which allows multiple instances to be added?

Comment: Thanks this seams interesting, do you know how it really works on the inside to be able to produce an order ( -1 or +1 ) between two equals but != strings?

Comment: It's quite interesting. It uses System.identityHashCode() as a first pass, and then if there are collisions, it maintains a list of UIDs for each new instance seen. See http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r311/trunk/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html

Comment: Very funny. I already used hashcode to make the distinction (return hash1 - hash2) but was not satisfied because of (unprobable) collisions.

Comment: hashCode by itself won't be enough, because hashCode() is typically consistent with equals(). You need to go back to the one on Object; hence identityHashCode().

Comment: @Sebastien Lorber: Using `return hash1 - hash2` is a common mistake. Because of overflow the resulting relation is not transitive.

Comment: @maaartinus by overflow do you mean that we overflow over the integer limits?

Comment: Yes... using this expression you get `0 < Integer.MAX_VALUE < Integer.MIN_VALUE < 0`, which is wrong. The overflow happens in the middle '<'.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following Comparator (for your example):

```
Comparator<String> comp = Ordering.natural().compound(Ordering.arbitrary());
```

This will sort things according to their natural Comparable ordering, but when the natural ordering is equal it will fall back to an arbitrary ordering so that distinct objects remain distinct.

Comment: thanks, i needed that guava arbitrary method. But +1 because you make obvious the use of such a feature

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's a great idea to do that. From the javadoc for `Comparator`:

> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of
>   imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set
>   (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit
>   comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If
>   the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will behave "strangely." In particular the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or
>   map), which is defined in terms of equals.

Comment: I understand what you mean and see some dangerous behavior that could happen (for exemple, havinga map with key1, retrieving the key1 entry with key2, but finally having !key1.equals(k2)). In my exemple it can be a problem, but i could have an equals method that make a distinction between two different instances.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a sorted collection with equal objects, you can put all your objects in a List and use Collections.sort().

Comment: @SebastienLorber - how would you retrieve something from a map if it contained multiple equal keys?

Comment: Basically the keys won't be equals because of different instances (my exemple with Strings is perhaps not appropriate because we can't edit that String equals)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `SortedSet<Collection<String>>` or similar, since - as you mentioned - a sorted doesn't allow you to add multiple equal entries.

Altenatively you can use Guava's [MultiSet](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

From the JavaDoc on `SortedSet`:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if the sorted set is to correctly implement the Set interface.

However, one question still remains: why do you want to have two distinct instances that are logically equal (that's what `equals()` actually means).

Answer (score -2):

The comparator should actualy return 0 only when the two references refer to the same object, like this:

```
public int compare(String s1,String s2) {
   if (s1!=s2) { 
      int result = s1.compareTo(s2);
      if (result == 0) {
          return -1;
      } else {
          return result;
      }
   } else {
      return 0;
   } 
}
```

Comment: We do not have compare(s1,s2) = -compare(s2,s1) there.

Comment: still, no  compare(s1,s2) = -compare(s2,s1)

Comment: This happens only when `s1` is actually the same string as `s2`. Do you also need that?

Comment: YES! basically my question is to provide a code for this specific case :) but the answer has already been provided